# Importance of + character in regex

Tags: regex, apache, .htaccess, mod-rewrite

I have this line in my .htacces file for certain redirects:

```
RewriteCond %{THE_REQUEST} \ /+directory/category/([A-Za-z0-9-]+)/(?:page|)/1/
```

However, I was wondering, what is the importance of the + character (before "directory")? For example, would the line still work in the same manner if I were to remove it as so?:

```
RewriteCond %{THE_REQUEST} \ /directory/category/([A-Za-z0-9-]+)/(?:page|)/1/
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is very specific purpose of `\ /+` in this `RewriteCond`. This is to match URLs like `http://domain.com////directory/category/cars/page/1/` (note multiple forward slashes after host name).

Of course it will also match regular cases like `http://domain.com/directory/category/cars/page/1/`